# Como posso fazer um rand() que sempre gere somente 4 números aleatórios?

Tags: php

Como posso fazer um `rand()` que **sempre** gere somente 4 números aleatórios, exemplo: 4562, 9370, 1028...

Meu código ele gera até 4 números, mas tem vez que sai 3.

```
$presenca = rand() % 4000;
```

Comment: Você quer sempre 4 dígitos?

Comment: Sim, quero apenas 4 dígitos!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se quer 4 dígitos então quer de 1000 à 9999, como ele gerará de 0, some 1000 para garantir o mínimo de 1000 e como já está somando mil estabeleça o limite em 9000.

```
$presenca = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
```

Também existe uma assinatura que devolve o resultado dentro da faixa:

```
rand(1000, 9999);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/RandomRange.php).

Note que se chamar assim o número máximo é colocado como argumento. Se usar a matemática precisa sempre colocar o primeiro número que não pode ser gerado, ou seja 10.000 não pode porque tem 5 dígitos, então usei 9000 (tirando os 1000 iniciais). isto é o que a função `rand()` faz internamente quando recebe os parâmetros de faixa. O resto de 9000 produzirá o valor máximo de 8999.

Comment: "como já está somando mil estabeleça o limite em 9000", não deveria ser 8999 então?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer editei para mostrar o motivo.

Answer (score 9):

Pode gerar um número com quatro dígitos informando os argumentos mínimo e máximo na chamada da função

```
$presenca = rand(1000, 9999);
```

Caso queira mostrar números menores que 1000 use `str_pad()` para adicionar zeros a esquerda. O primeiro argumento é o número, o segundo o tamanho máximo da string, terceiro o caracter(es) que serão adicionados e último argumento  é onde devem ser adicionados esses caracter(es) direita (por padrão), esquerda ou em ambos os lados.

```
$n = rand(1, 9999);
echo str_pad($n, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Documentação - rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

[Documentação - str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer só passando os argumentos na função, é mais simples:

```
$presenca = rand( int $min , int $max );
$presenca = rand( 1000, 9999 );
```

> Veja mais na documentação:
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php